# I'm getting an error with System.out.printf()

Tags: java, eclipse, printf

I am getting a run time error and I cannot figure out why. Although I have figured out that it is happening because of the following line of code.

```
System.out.printf("\n\nThe total bill for your group is $%.2f before taxes. The HST (13%) will be $%.2f.", totalBill, amountOfTax);
```

totalBill and amountOfTax are both float type variables.

I am fairly new to programming and have hardly any experience with using printf. I have a very similar line of code earlier in the program that does essentially the same thing and it runs fine.

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ')'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2579)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2555)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at RestaurantOrder.main(RestaurantOrder.java:220)
```

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it!

ps. I should note that I am using Eclipse Luna (4.4.0)

Comment: remember that % is an active character for printf. See that "HST (13%)" bit? That's going to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percent sign for `(13%)` is being interpreted as a placeholder.  It's looking for characters after the `%` for details about how to format a variable there, and `)` isn't valid.

You meant to have a literal `%` in the output, not interpreted as a placeholder.  It must escaped with another `%` sign.  Try:

```
System.out.printf(
  "\n\nThe total bill for your group is $%.2f before taxes. The HST (13%%) will be $%.2f.",
  totalBill, amountOfTax);
```

See the [`Formatter` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for details:

> The format specifiers which do not correspond to arguments have the following syntax:
>
> ```
> %[flags][width]conversion
> ```

And

> '%'   percent The result is a literal '%' ('\u0025')

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape % sign in [format string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). "13%" becomes "13%%":

```
System.out.printf("\n\nThe total bill for your group is $%.2f before taxes. " + 
    "The HST (13%%) will be $%.2f.", totalBill, amountOfTax);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape literal '%' signs in format strings as "%%", e.g. "(13%%)".

`printf` looks for format specifiers that start with '%', so in your case it sees "%)" and gets confused, wondering what the ')' is for.

Your error message gives a good hint:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ')'
```

It is choking on a ')', when you see an error like that, look for that character in your string and you will generally find the problem in that vicinity.

The [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) isn't really that obvious about it, but a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) shows the details.